# qtbase5-dev : Depends: libgles2-mesa-dev or libgles2-dev but it is not installable

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5, apt-get

I'm trying to install the qt5 development libraries using `sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev`, but I'm getting an error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qtbase5-dev : Depends: libgles2-mesa-dev or
                        libgles2-dev but it is not installable
               Depends: libqt5gui5 (= 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqt5printsupport5 (= 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqt5widgets5 (= 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libqt5opengl5-dev (= 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The problem is I don't have held packages - I checked using [dpkg --get-selections | grep hold](https://askubuntu.com/a/223267/10263), but it showed nothing.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using ancient Qt versions from the repository rather than something more up-to-date from the Qt website?

Comment: @ddriver Sorry, but I didn't quite understand that. Are you asking why I'm using `apt-get`? It's just that it's the default package manager on Ubuntu and using it "just works" (well, not in this case).

Comment: I am asking why are you using a nearly 3 year old Qt version. apt get is ok in most cases, but it is lagging behind on Qt version.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this was caused by the oibaf graphics PPA being installed.

`sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`

will revert to stock graphics libs.

Answer (score 1):

Manually installing `libgles2-mesa-dev` and then `qtbase5-dev` worked. I had to ran it in separate commands though:

```
sudo apt-get install libgles2-mesa-dev
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev
```